# How can we set right-to-left Kendo UI in Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, right-to-left

in my new project of Angular, I'm using Kendo UI and in my project. I need to show all of the data rights to left because of the Arabic language and Farsi.

I can set direction RTL and make all of element right to left but I
try to find a more deep and better solution.

Does anybody have some ideas?

Comment: if you landed here looking for RTL support for kenod Angular inputs, then sadly this isnt supported. but you vote for it to be [here](https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1417261-rtl-support-for-kendo-kendodateinputs)

Answer (score 3):

A way can be using kendo UI RTL:

in your app module:

```
import { RTL } from '@progress/kendo-angular-l10n';
```

and in providers:

```
providers: [{ provide: RTL, useValue: true }]
```

[**Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfiiv4)